# what does 'Create Unique Index' do?

Tags: sql-server, index

Let's say we have a emptyCustomers table (CustID, Age, FirstName), and we create a unique non-clustered index on Age column. Obviously, there could be a lot of duplicates on Age. So what does  'Create Unique NONCLUSTERED Index  XXX' do here? Do it mean once I add a person whose age is 22 in the table, I can't add another person whose age is 22 too? Can't we alter the table definition to add a unique constraint to achieve the same goal?

Another thing confused me a lot is, my textbook says:

***"SQL Server forces any clustered indexes to be unique — even if you don’t define them that way. Fortunately, it does this in a way that doesn’t change how you use the index. You can still insert duplicate rows if you want, but SQL Server adds a suffix to the key internally to ensure that the row has a unique identifier"***

so why can't non clustered index does the same thing by adding a suffix to duplicate row

Comment: you could answer some of these questions via [experimentation](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l)

Answer (score 1):

> what does 'Create Unique NONCLUSTERED Index XXX' do here? Does it mean
>   once I add a person whose age is 22 in the table, I can't add another
>   person whose age is 22 too?

Yes - it enforces that the combination of key values are all `DISTINCT`. If you only have one key column then that will enforce only one row per distinct value of that column.

> Can't we alter the table definition to add a unique constraint to
>   achieve the same goal?

Yes. A unique constraint will create a unique index implicitly to enforce the constraint efficiently. There is not much difference in what you choose to enforce this here. Some minor differences are that the constraint has some additional metadata overhead as it is an object in its own right and gets an entry in `sys.objects` - this metadata can be useful when trying to determine creation or last modified date. A unique index can be filtered a constraint cannot.

> "SQL Server forces any clustered indexes to be unique ... you can still insert duplicate
>   rows if you want, but SQL Server adds a suffix to the key internally
>   to ensure that the row has a unique identifier"
>
> so why can't non clustered index does the same thing by adding a
>   suffix to duplicate row

If you want to be able to add duplicate key values to a nonclustered index then simply omit the `unique` keyword in the `CREATE INDEX`.

Behind the scenes SQL Server will still ensure it is unique in a similar way to clustered indexes. The row locator (clustered index key if applicable or physical RID on a heap) will be implicitly added to the non clustered index key columns to ensure the full key is unique.

One difference when compared with the `uniqueifier` is that this is added to all rows not just duplicates.